# PostMessage Delphi Firefox

Tags: delphi, winapi

Я успешно отправляю это сообщение в блокнот, но совсем нет реакции в браузере. Я использовал Spyxx.exe чтобы отлавливать message. Когда я отправлял сообщение в блокнот, я вижу в Spyxx.exe (вкладка message), что сообщения есть, когда отправляю в браузер - совсем пусто, как будто я не посылаю в браузер ничего. Хочу узнать в чём дело.

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
Vcl.StdCtrls;
             
 type
TForm2 = class(TForm)
Button1: TButton;
  end;
             
var
Form2: TForm2;
             
implementation
             
{$R *.dfm}
    procedure TF1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      str: AnsiChar;
      str2: string;
      i: Integer;
    begin
        hw := 2098120;
        str2 := 'alert("kuku")';
        for i := 0 to str2.length do
          begin
          str := AnsiChar(str2[i]);
          PostMessage(hw, WM_CHAR, Word(str), 0);
        end;
     end;
```

Comment: Причин может быть несколько, а последствия - разными :) Для начала - совершенно непонятно, откуда взялся hardcoded hwnd, какой реакции вы ожидаете и зачем вам WM_CHAR, когда скорее всего (телепатически) требуется https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: hw(2098120) = HWND браузера(Firefox), получил из Spy++.exe, на тот момент(делал проверки - браузер находит). Отправлять нажатия кнопок у меня получается, моя цель отправить js код в Консоль.